# Order by works inside base but doesn't in runtime report

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, report

I've tried to do a report order by date for almost 2 weeks and still no working properly, and I don't know what can I do anymore :(

This sounds like this, I've a report with 5 fields, one of them is invisible, the Last field of the report is called DEVOLUCAO,  and I need my report order by that field ascending, that's the problem, I do a query that works properly in database (access),  that works properly in preview data of dataset (visual studio 2010), but in run time it doesn't work, I've already modified the sort expressions in tablix, and do it too on each field of report, but all my ideas has gone...

So I'm using this code to select data:

Select idemprestimo, nomeleitor, titulo, saida, devolucao from tbemprestimohistorico order by devolucao asc

So with this query I can make the report, the report is generated but don't order by devolucao asc, and in preview data it works, directly inside the base it works too, but in run time don't...

So, since the  thanks for help

Ps* I'm using vb. Net and access and working on windows form

Comment: Please use code tag to show your sql statment.  Can  you show your other code, and explain what isn't working

Comment: Hi, when I get home, can I put images here? , cause if I can I'll put more details and images and try to explain a little more

Comment: don't put images.  Copy and paste your code.  Use the {} code button to format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever use sorting on the recordsource of an Access report. It will be ignored and may even slow down the opening of the report.

Always apply all sorting in the report itself.

Comment: good evening my friend, sorry 4 delay, but I´d some problems here, so, like u said, I used sorting in the report and it works perfectly...so thank u and once more sorry 4 delay ;)

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted out!